# Запрос sql с параметром и отображение в textbox с#

Tags: c#, sql

Есть две таблицы, в одну заносятся данные об эксперименте, в другую добавляется информация об выбранной клавиатуре (поле Nklav типа число либо 1, либо 2). В форме с результатами у каждого эксперимента есть текстбокс, в который я заношу данные по выбранной в данном эксперименте клавиатуре, вот как я это делаю

```
SqlConnection ThisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=STAS-ПК  \SQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog= SMSensomotorica2db; User ID=sa;Password= novell");
ThisConnection.Open();
SqlCommand thisCommand = ThisConnection.CreateCommand();
thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT  top 1  Nklav FROM  nomerKlava ORDER BY ind desc";
SqlDataReader thisReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
string res = string.Empty;
while (thisReader.Read())
{
    res += thisReader["Nklav"];
}
thisReader.Close();
ThisConnection.Close();
textBox1.Text = res;
```

[image: Вопрос]

однако каждый раз когда я выполняю новый эксперимент, во всех результатах отображается именно последняя выбранная клавиатура. Как добавить в запрос параметр с идентификатором эксперимента?

```
(id_exp = @curr_id_exp)
```

Comment: Конечно отображается последняя клавиатура, ведь Вы именно это и спрашиваете в запросе. Попробуйте, например, так: thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_exp", idExp) а в текст запроса добавить условие "where id_exp = @id_exp"

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо,все получилось!

Comment: @AleksandrZharinov Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я не уверен что это был полноценный вопрос. Но если Вы настаиваете.

Comment: @AleksandrZharinov Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добавить параметр в запрос необходимо изменить текст запроса, добавив в него условие "where id_exp = @id_exp".
Кроме этого надо добавить параметр в команду:

```
thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_exp", idExp)
```

Не забыв при этом предварительно объявить и заполнить переменную idExp нужными данными.